# how can I hide Element inside the innerHtml in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have below calculator code , what I want to do is when I click calculate button,when "Additional Ongoing Deployment" this input value (id=SNEAD ) = 0, the result should hide from the output (which id is ong1), if !=0 then show it, the calculation output is innerHTML,so I was wondering if I can use "if else" statement inside the innerHTML?? At the moment my solution is add id ong1 and use  `$('.ong1').show();`  `$('.ong1').hide();` but it is not working,

It is too long, please see my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/jackwei/9co5s07w/58/

below is the js code:

```html
    <script>
        function calculation() {
            var SNE = document.getElementById("SNE").value;
            var MNE = document.getElementById("MNE").value;
            var SAE = document.getElementById("SAE").value;
            var MAE = document.getElementById("MAE").value;
            var MAEAD = document.getElementById("MAEAD").value;
            var first4Value = document.getElementById("first4Value").value;
            var SNEAD = document.getElementById("SNEAD").value;
            var MNEAD = document.getElementById("MNEAD").value;
            var SAEAD = document.getElementById("SAEAD").value;
            var MAEAD = document.getElementById("MAEAD").value;
            var result = document.getElementById("result");
            var resultall = document.getElementById("resultall");
            var ToEmail = document.getElementById("ToEmail");
            var ToName = document.getElementById("ToName"); 
            var calc = (SNE * 1 + SAE * 1) * 1 + (MNE * 1 + MAE * 1) * 1.5 + SNE * 0.75 + MNE * 1 + SAE * 0.75 + MAE * 1 + SNE * 2 + MNE * 3 + SAE * 1 + MAE * 2 + SNEAD * 0.5 + MNEAD * 0.5 + SAEAD * 0.5 + MAEAD * 0.5;
            var TSNE = SNE * 2 + SNE * 1 + SNE * 0.75 + SNEAD * 0.5;
            var TMNE = MNE * 3 + MNE * 1.5 + MNE * 1 + MNEAD * 0.5;
            var TQTY = SNE * 1 + MNE * 1 + SAE * 1 + MAE * 1;
            var TSAE = SAE * 1 + SAE * 1 + SAE * 0.75 + SAEAD * 0.5;
            var TMAE = MAE * 2 + MAE * 1.5 + MAE * 1 + MAEAD * 0.5;
            var ongoing = SNEAD * 0.5 + MNEAD * 0.5 + SAEAD * 0.5 + MAEAD * 0.5;
            var THRS = TSNE + TMNE + TSAE + TMAE;
            result.innerHTML = "Your EDM Quote Total is: <b>" + THRS + " Hours</b> <br/><br/><b>Quote Breakup:</b>" + "<br><br><table width=\'330\' bgcolor=\'white\' border=\'1\' bordercolor=\'black\' cellpadding=\'1\' cellspacing=\'1\' class=\'caltable\'>\n" +
                        "   <tr style=width:330px;background-color:#44546A;color:#FFFFFF;>\n" +
                        "        <td></td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=font-size:11px;>New Simple</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=font-size:11px;>New Medium</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=font-size:11px;>Adapt. Simple</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=font-size:11px;>Adapt. Medium</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=font-size:11px;>Total</td>\n" +
                        "        </tr>\n"
                        +
                        "   <tr style=max-width:310px>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#5B9BD5;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;>Quantity</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + SNE + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + MNE + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + SAE + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + MAE + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;><b>" + TQTY + "</b></td>\n" +
                        "        </tr>\n"
                        +
                        "   <tr style=max-width:310px>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>Build</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>2</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>3</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>2</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;></td>\n"
                        +
                        "   <tr style=max-width:310px>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>QC & Approvals</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1.5</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1.5</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;></td>\n" +
                        "        </tr>\n"
                        +
                        "   <tr style=max-width:310px>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>One Deployment & Reports</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>0.75</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>0.75</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>1</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#eef9fe;color:#000000;font-size:11px;></td>\n"
                        +
                        "   <tr style=max-width:310px>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#5B9BD5;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;>Additional Ongoing Deployment(s)</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + SNEAD + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + MNEAD + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + SAEAD + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;>" + MAEAD + "</td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#D3EBF7;color:#000000;font-size:11px;></td>\n"
                        +
                        "   <tr style=max-width:310px>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#5B9BD5;color:#ffffff;font-size:12px;><b>Total Hours</b></td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#BDD7EE;color:#000000;font-size:12px;><b>" + TSNE + "</b></td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#BDD7EE;color:#000000;font-size:12px;><b>" + TMNE + "</b></td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#BDD7EE;color:#000000;font-size:12px;><b>" + TSAE + "</b></td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#BDD7EE;color:#000000;font-size:12px;><b>" + TMAE + "</b></td>\n" +
                        "        <td style=background-color:#BDD7EE;color:#000000;font-size:12px;><b>" + THRS + "</b></td>\n"
                        +
                        "</table>";
 if(SNEAD !== 0)
 {
  $('.ong1').show();
 }  
 else  if(SNEAD == 0)
 {
  $('.ong1').hide();
 }    
                        
             resultall.innerHTML = "<B>Inclusion:</B><br /><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> " + SNE + " New simple builds <span id=ong1>with " + SNEAD + " additional <span style=padding-left:34px;>deployments</span></span></span>" + "<br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> " + MNE + " New medium builds with " +  MNEAD + " additional <span style=padding-left:34px;>deployments</span></span>"  + "<br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> " + SAE + " adaption simple builds with " + SAEAD + " additional <span style=padding-left:34px;>deployments</span></span>"+ "<br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> " + MAE + " Adaption medium builds with " + MAEAD + " additional <span style=padding-left:34px;>deployments</span></span>"
                        +
                        "<br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Mobile responsive email build/s</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Standard Reports Covers:</span><br /><span style=padding-left:30px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Suppressions on upload</span><br /> <span style=padding-left:30px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Sent report (Sent, Opens, Clicks, Bounces, <span style=padding-left:38px;>Unsubscribes)</span></span><br /> <span style=padding-left:30px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Click Report (Unique Clicks, Total Clicks per <span style=padding-left:38px;>link)</span></span>    <br /><span style=padding-left:30px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Click Report (Unique Clicks, Total Clicks per <span style=padding-left:38px;>link)</span></span>  <br /><br /><b>Exclusions:</b><br /><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Archiving</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Change requests</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Additional report</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Creative services</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Data manipulation</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Data transformation </span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Data extraction</span><br /><span style=padding-left:15px;><span style=font-size:18px;>•</span> Any automation</span> "
          

            success([0, 1], null, null);
            document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
                location.href = "email.html?SNE=" + SNE + "&SNEAD=" + SNEAD + "&TSNE=" + TSNE + "&SAE=" + SAE + "&SAEAD=" + SAEAD + "&TSAE=" + TSAE + "&MNE=" + MNE + "&MNEAD=" + MNEAD + "&TMNE=" + TMNE + "&MAE=" + MAE + "&MAEAD=" + MAEAD + "&TMAE=" + TMAE + "&TQTY=" + TQTY + "&THRS=" + THRS + "&ToName=" + $("#ToName").val() + "&ToEmail=" + $("#ToEmail").val();
            };
        }


</script>
```

Comment: callElementById uses `#` as explained in [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). But your trying to call class by using `.`

Comment: @MarkBaijens if you go through his code there is no `document.getElementById()`. for ong

Comment: Is your fiddle working? The HTML seems to be broken. You are using $(".ong1") instead of $("#ong1") since ong1 is id of the HTML tag. You have style on ongo1 class in css but there is no such class in HTML.

Comment: Would tell innerHTML is a bad idea - in case you want to work with its object, it would be better to create elements by DOM - they will not exist for some time if created from string and do not know if there is any simple way to know when they are ready. Check probably ways like document.createElement("tagName"), element.appendChild, etc.

Comment: even I changed to # and add document.getElementById(). 
 it is still not working, is there any way to achive this? can I use if else condition inside the innerHTML? https://jsfiddle.net/jackwei/9co5s07w/63/